# How do you make a JFrame intangible?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Im a real novice at java coding and for just a little project I'd like the following code to be untouchable eg. anything behind the frame(and its contents) can be clicked on. But I don't know how to do it! I've searched everywhere but haven't found anything.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.swing.*;

public class swag {
    static Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize(); 
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
    JLabel lb = new JLabel();
    lb.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic",Font.PLAIN,50));
    lb.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lb.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    lb.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(dim.width,100);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(f.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setUndecorated(true);
    f.add(lb);
    f.setVisible(true);

    int r=255;int g=0;int b=0; 
    int a=80;int t=15;
    while(true){
        while(true){
            lb.setText((System.currentTimeMillis()+""));
            f.setBackground(new Color(r--,g++,0,a));
            Thread.sleep(t);
        if(r==0&&g==255){break;}
    }   while(true){
            lb.setText((System.currentTimeMillis()+""));
            f.setBackground(new Color(0,g--,b++,a));
            Thread.sleep(t);
        if(g==0&&b==255){break;}
    } while(true){
            lb.setText((System.currentTimeMillis()+""));
            f.setBackground(new Color(r++,0,b--,a));
            Thread.sleep(t);
        if(b==0&&r==255){break;}
        }}}
}//class
```

Note: haven't worked on efficiency yet :)

Comment: If you want the frame to be transparent to the events then I don't think it's possible, best you can do is use `java.awt.Robot` class to detect the clicked location screen and then if it's on the frame use robot to replay it behind it.

Comment: I thought about it, but once all the blue print code is out I'm planning on making it more efficient. I can imagine that'd take up alot of B's with those listeners.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by B's but yes it would take 2 listeners, Mouse and Keyboard. Also in my experience Robot is not reliable, once the window which loaded Robot is minimized, sometimes it stops listening. Best solution would be to implement something in C/C++ and use that to detect events and load it in Java with JNI

Comment: what is the purpose of having a window that you can not be clicked , this could be ok for search/replace dialog , or inner frames but almost useless for a normal aplication

Comment: @whyn0t Something like KeyLogger can be thought to be an application of this usecase.

Comment: @11thdimension B's = Bytes. Or I could add a invisible button that has more reliable listeners. Hmmm... thanks for the help. Wasn't sure if there was an easy way or not.

Comment: @whyn0t many screen themes and displays have unclickable objects :)

Comment: then he use C and some DLL injection to intercept events from the active window and save himself some time :)

Comment: @whyn0t You're right, it would be easier to do in C or C++ however, they may not support the same platform independence that Java does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about the [glass pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) of JFrame. Using it you are able to show the UI components but block all user interactions.

Example:

```
public class FreezePane extends JComponent {
    public FreezePane() {
        // trap mouse, key, and focus events
        addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() );
        addMouseMotionListener( new MouseMotionAdapter() );
        addKeyListener( new KeyAdapter() );
        addFocusListener( new FocusListener() {
            // do not let any component take focus while visible
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                requestFocusInWindow();
            }
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Then just set the glass pane and make it visible.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setGlassPane( new FreePane() );
frame.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
```

Comment: but block all user interactions. != GlassPane doesn't protect against KeyEvent(s), its required to consume()